# Containg image when enlarging

Tags: css, animate.css, image-enlarge

I have three images in a row. They enlarge on mouseover. The problem is that when they enlarge they crossover into the surrounding elements. My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user3052443/cywfj85v/3/) is here. The red border represents the overall container and the black border represents the individual image containers.  So what I am trying to do is enlarge each image on mouseover but the enlargement should not go outside of the black  border. I've searched for solutions for this and the ones I found said to use overflow:hidden but that doesn't seem to be making a difference. Would someone please point out the mistake?

```
    .container {height:40px;border:1px solid red}
    .nav {margin:0; padding-top:5px;overflow:hidden}
    .nav-items {border:1px solid black}
    #set2 {margin-left:0px; display:inline-block}
    #set2:hover {  
      -webkit-animation: enlarge 5s;
      animation: enlarge 2s 1 forwards;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes enlarge {
      100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
        transform: scale(2.1);
      }
    }


    <div class="banner_set"> 
     <div class="container"> 
      <ul class="nav">
        <li id="set2" class="nav-items"><a href="example.com"><img src="example1.jpg"></a></li>
        <li id="set2" class="nav-items"><a href="example.com"><img src="example2.jpg"></a></li>
        <li id="set2" class="nav-items"><a href="example.com"><img src="example3.jpg"></a></li>
       </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you update your fiddle with working images?  Your local paths don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First up, you're using duplicate IDs (which you shouldn't do).

Second, you're scaling the container, not the image.
Update your styles so that:

```
.nav-items {margin-left:0px; display:inline-block; overflow: hidden;}
.nav-items:hover img {  
  -webkit-animation: enlarge 5s;
  animation: enlarge 2s 1 forwards;
}
```

This way your container stays the same size, with hidden overflow, but your images scale on hover.

Here's an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cywfj85v/4/)